# how to connect mongodb on localhost:27017 in window?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, localhost, robo3t

**mongodb.bat**
"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongo.exe" --dbpath "f:\mongodb\data"

My localhost Run on port : **8080**

i can't mongodb connect Robomongo..

How connect robomongo connect to mongodb for Node.js in Windows8.1 64-bit ?

**See the Image ---**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAkz8.png)

Comment: enter your folder path containing mongodb

Comment: I have never used Robomongo in Windows before. But you have to start MongoDB service by running `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe` first.

Comment: did you installed mongodb?

Comment: mongodb already install

Comment: Thank You , Ashish Choudhary

Comment: i miss folder path.

Answer (score 2):

Your `mongodb.bat` should change to:

```
"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe" --dbpath "f:\mongodb\data"
```

Answer (score 0):

go to bin folder inside your mongodb folder and then follow this command

```
D:\mongodb\bin>mongod --dbpath d:\mongodb\data\db
```

make sure that your mongodb folder contains `data` and `db` folder

Answer (score 0):

Robombongo 0.9.0 has no support for MongoDB 3.4. 
Please use [Robomongo 1.1 - Beta version with MongoDB 3.4 Support](https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/1250#issuecomment-301036770).